# Ruby on Rails validation by pair of properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to do validation on my model on Ruby on Rails.

I have model with 2 fields:

user_id
some_item_id

And I have many rows in DB with the same user_id, but with different some_item_id. And I need avoid duplication of this some_item_id towards to specific user_id.

In Rails exist some 'magic' validation in one line for this?

Comment: You Can do this by Uniqueness helper.Please Check this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

Comment: It is also a good practice to add a SQL unique index on those two columns. Reasons are described here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`validates : user_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => : some_item_id }`