# Ruby on Rails validation does not work for two fields in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am new in Ruby and Ruby on Rails, so maybe my question is not appropriate. I am making a Tic Tac Toe game and when I try to validate my player names like this:

```
  validates_presence_of :player_1, :player_2
  validates_uniqueness_of :player_1
  validates_uniqueness_of :player_2
```

And do this in my config/initializers/cleaner.rb

```
Game.destroy_all
```

my validation does not work. I also tried [Ruby on Rails validation by pair of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479093/ruby-on-rails-validation-by-pair-of-properties), but it does not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What error message are you getting? Have you tried to create an instance of Game which tests those validations?

Comment: Validation is not working, if I put two same names I can play the game. Yes, I made a insance of the new game. @margo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
validates : player_1, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => : player_2 }
validates : player_2, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => : player_1 }
```

OR

```
validates :player_1, uniqueness: { scope: :player_2 }
validates :player_2, uniqueness: { scope: :player_1 }
```

Comment: Your solution helped. Tnx @prashant4020